# Why would remote desktop from Windows 7 to Windows 7 always time out the first time?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

At the keyboard of my laptop running Windows 7 Premium Home - mstsc to my desktop downstairs on Windows 7 Ultimate.  Every time, without fail, the first attempt can't connect.  2nd attempt connects immediately.  Until the desktop reboots, connecting is instantaneous.  In fact, if I try to connect, cancel immediately, and then try again, I connect immediately, too.

So it's not a timeout, it just needs to be poked.  Doesn't matter how long the machine has been up, it's just the first RDP connection after boot that bombs.  Any ideas?

(It's not sleeping, hibernating, etc.)

Comment: Is the NIC set to power off after x minutes? Also, is mstsc the only thing that fails like this? Does file sharing, ping, etc work fine?

Comment: @MarkM NIC doesn't power off (all power-saving is disabled, save for the monitor).  Yes, only with RDP, everything else is zippy quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only assume this was fixed in a patch at some point. The behavior stopped without my noticing.

Comment: If somebody has an answer for this, it would be interesting - the behaviour is still present on my system.